# Birt report showing ascii values in column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, report, birt

I have a small issue using birt report.

I have made a report which uses stored procedures accessing data from MySql DB which is hosted on a server.

When I check the data through SP,It gives the correct result. However when I call the SP through BIRT report It displays **ASCII Values**.

I also tried changing the column type from blob to string in BIRT report but its showing the same value.

I also tried converting the ASCII code to string using javascript but it displays blank column.

Please refer attached screenshot for reference.
[image: ASCII value in birt report column]

**EDIT

Also find the output column screenshot:

[image: Output Columns screenshot]

Below are my machine configurations

OpenText Analytics Designer 
Version: 4.6.0
Build id: v20160406

windows machine 8.1

MySql 5.5

Any feedback would be most welcome.
Thanks

Comment: What's the type return in your SP? Is it a String? Could you add the 'output columns' screen shot too?

Comment: @FannyV: Added the output column screeshot.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had an exact similar kind of issue for my BIRT Report, so had to make the following changes to mySQL SP:

Instead of selecting a variable from the SP, I declared an OUT parameter in the SP and fetched the parameter in a variable while calling the SP.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `mySP`(IN hts VARCHAR(10),
OUT var1 varchar (20),
OUT var2 varchar (20))
BEGIN
select col1 into var1 from Table1 where col2 = hts;
select col3 into var2 from table1 where col2 = hts;
select var1, var2;
END
```

And while calling the SP in your BIRT report, you can call the SP in the dataset like this:

```
call mySP(hts, @var1, @var2);
```

This will give you the exact values of var1,var2 instead of **ASCII values.**

Hope this solves your issue. :)